# Contacts app for wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I tried to create a contact app for wp7. In the app start up, i am able to get the contact list and also the contact number but if i clicked on the contact number, i am not able make a call to that number. Below is the listbox used in xaml for obtaining contact number, i have used a tap function for the listbox-

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PhoneNumbers}" FontSize="64" Height="100"  Margin="0,50,0,0" Tap="ListBox_Tap">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=PhoneNumber, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

But in the tap event-

```
PhoneCallTask PhoneTask = new PhoneCallTask();
PhoneTask.PhoneNumber = **Don't know what to write here!!!**
PhoneTask.Show();
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance for your hard work!

Answer (score 1):

You are making life harder than it really is.

A few things:
1. The AddressChooser task I believe only gives you access to the display name and the address of the selected contact. You are better off using the Contact API included with Mango. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286416(v=vs.92).aspx

2. If you continue to use AddressChooser, bind the data you obtain in the AddressChooser_Completed method using the event arguments. There is no need to renavigate to your page and subscribe to onNavigated events.

It looks like you want images, so you really do want to use the new Contact APIs. They give you much more information and aggregates contacts from all sources(i.e Facebook, Google)

Comment: Now i have edited my post, and now am able to obtain the Contact Number but i don't know how to make a call with that!

Comment: Here's a thought.
Instead of making the phone number a textblock, you could make it a button that fires an event, where the content property is bound to the phone number. Then, in that event, cast the sender argument into a button and take the button.content property as the phone number

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the caller's number after being clicked using the SelectedItem property of the ListBox.

Comment: I think selectedItem is what am searching for. Can you give any example or sample codes here?

Comment: I don't know exactly what type of collection is bound to the ListBox, but something like "PhoneTask.PhoneNumber = ( ( TheTypeOfSingleItemsOfTheCollection )ListBoxName.SelectedItem ).PhoneNumberProperty.ToString();"

Comment: But there is an error says- **TheTypeOfSingleItemsOfTheCollection** could not be found, Are you missing any reference.

Comment: I mean you have to replace these texts by appropriate class types that are contained in the collection you are binding